# How do I correct settings for Collapse Blast to access Facebook?

Tags: iphone, games

I installed Collapse Blast on my iPhone 4 and I can't log in to play. I get an error message that the game can't access Facebook and to change it in settings.

I have changed everything, uninstalled and reinstalled and still won't work.

Answer (score 1):

The best place for support for Collapse Blast will be the creator's [GameHouse Support site](https://support.gamehouse.com/home). GameHouse are best placed to answer this question.